# Image classification with an associated matrix

Tags: classification, neural-networks, dataset, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of images with 9 different classes. However, there are different categories with the same type of associated image and only can be differentiated with an associated matrix in my specific problem.

I want to train a neural network with the images and the associated matrix as inputs. What type of architecture is good to use? Or where can I find bibliography about it?

Thanks for the help.

regards.

Comment: You may want to research "wide and deep networks"

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion led me to a type of architecture that can help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic is multimodal neural networks.

Here some repositories that i hope will help me a lot

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1z8-GeTXvSuVbcez8R6HOG1Tw_F3A-WETahQdTV38_uc/edit#slide=id.g1ea5aac985_0_892

https://github.com/prml615/prml

https://github.com/husseinmozannar/multimodal-deep-learning-for-disaster-response

https://github.com/guillaume-be/multimodal-avito

Thanks to kbrose, his suggestion led me to this type of architectures.